How do I get the output values of the loop into a separate variable?
BAT/CMD. For example, this loop outputs all txt files from a folder.
@echo off
FOR %%a IN (C:\myfolder\*.txt) DO echo %%a
pause

Out:
C:\myfolder\4234.txt
C:\myfolder\out88888.txt
C:\myfolder\tmp01.txt
C:\myfolder\tmp2.txt

How do I change the loop so that paths are written to variables? These variables should be used below in the script
var1 = C:\myfolder\4234.txt
var2 = C:\myfolder\out88888.txt
var3 = C:\myfolder\tmp01.txt
var4 = C:\myfolder\tmp2.txt

I do not know what to write here, I'm just asking)

I suggest you to review this answer

You can use enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set #N=0& FOR %%A IN (C:\myfolder\*.txt) DO set /a #N+=1& set "var!#N!=%%~fA"
set var
pause

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set #N=0
FOR %%A IN (C:\myfolder\*.txt) DO (
    set /a #N+=1
    set "var!#N!=%%~fA"
)
set var
pause

set var to show all var
set var2 to show only var2, or Echo %var2%, for example

I'd consider doing it like this, without reliance on delayed variable expansion.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "DirPath=C:\myfolder"
Set "FileExt=.txt"

For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('(Set var^) 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('
 Set "PathExt=" ^&
 %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%DirPath%":"*%FileExt%" 2^>NUL ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /NR "$"
 ') Do Set "var%%G=%%H"
(Set var) 2>NUL && Pause

The first For loop is designed to ensure that you do not already have existing variables named beginning var. The last line is included just to show you any var named variables defined within the second For loop together with their respective values.

I split the second For loop above over multiple lines for readability. You are free to join those five lines back to a single line if you wish.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "DirPath=C:\myfolder"
Set "FileExt=.txt"

For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('(Set var^) 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('Set "PathExt=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%DirPath%":"*%FileExt%" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /NR "$"') Do Set "var%%G=%%H"
(Set var) 2>NUL && Pause

